# Which byte-compile-file is my Emacs using? Function signature in describe-function differs to that in bytecomp.el

Tags: help, byte-compilation

After reviewing some functions in my own dot-emacs files, I've noticed that the function signature that `describe-function` shows for `byte-compile-file` differs to that for the function definition in the Emacs Lisp source code visible after `find-function` for `byte-compile-file`.

The function signature that I'm seeing with `describe-function`:

```
(byte-compile-file FILENAME)
```

The function signature visible in `bytecomp.el.gz` after `find-function`:

```
(byte-compile-file filename &optional load)
```

I've noticed this with Emacs 28 from openSUSE OBS (openSUSE Tumbleweed) and in Emacs 29 from the emacs-devel ports in FreeBSD ports.

When I noticed this peculiarity, I was trying to revise a hack in my own dot-emacs files, such that would ostensibly byte-compile any source file that does not have a byte compiled file or for which the source file is newer than the first matching byte-compiled file, then writing to a byte compiled dest filename at some translated pathname under user-init-dir. It would load the byte-compiled file by default. It's not been working out, per se - hence the debugging. Considering the previous, I'm not even sure if I can be certain of what byte-compile-file function it's calling.

Could it be simply a quirk in `describe-function`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one function of a given name at a time. `describe-function` tells you what file the function was defined in, and clicking the link takes you directly to it. When a function is redefined, the new function replaces the old and new metadata about the source of the function replaces the old metadata. Thus `find-function` and `describe-function` will always send you to the correct definition. ¹

If you look closely at the definition in bytecomp.el, you will notice that it has a declaration:

```
(declare (advertised-calling-convention (filename) "28.1"))
```

This is a way of deprecating arguments. `byte-compile-file` used to take an optional argument, but in Emacs 28.1 they deprecated it. The argument is still there in the real argument list so that old code will continue to run without error, but the documentation doesn’t mention it and this declaration completely hides it. You can call `emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load` if you wish to immediately load the file that you have compiled.

You can get more information by looking at the help for `set-advertised-calling-convention`.

¹: There is, of course, a caveat. It is possible to define a function that has no stable source location, in which case that part of the metadata will be empty. `find-function` will tell you that it doesn’t know where the function is defined, and `describe-function` will omit the link. The easiest way to do this is to type a definition into a buffer that is not associated with a file, such as the `*scratch*` buffer, and evaluate it there with `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Due to the difference in the function signature, I wasn't sure if the `byte-compile-file` definition I was looking at - from `find-function` - if it had represented the definition of the `byte-compile-file` that Emacs was using, in this instance. 

It's informative to learn about this matter of calling conventions in Emacs.